# Run Specflow with Xunit but gives error nunit.framework

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, xunit

I'm having a weird problem, have googled everywhere and it point out what I have already done,

I have a simple specflow that test a login, but after the browser is opening, i get this error.

```
Test Name:  Check if Login is working
Test FullName:  SpecFlow.GeneratedTests.UITest.Smoke.Features.LoginFeature.CheckIfLoginIsWorking
Test Source:    C:\**\Login.feature : line 7
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:02,676

Result StackTrace:  
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.UnitTestRuntimeProviderHelper.GetAssertMethodWithFormattedMessage(String assemblyName, String typeName, String methodName)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.NUnitRuntimeProvider.TestInconclusive(String message)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
   at SpecFlow.GeneratedTests.UITest.Smoke.Features.LoginFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
   at SpecFlow.GeneratedTests.UITest.Smoke.Features.LoginFeature.CheckIfLoginIsWorking() in C:\**\Login.feature:line 17
Result Message: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have also changed the `app.config` file to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>,
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xunit.diagnosticMessages" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="xUnit"/>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
    <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic" />
    </stepAssemblies>
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

The weird thing is that if i run a normal selenium test ( Not specflow ) it works directly.

This is also a part of the generated feature file

```
 using TechTalk.SpecFlow;


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "2.1.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    public partial class LoginFeature : Xunit.IClassFixture<LoginFeature.FixtureData>, System.IDisposable
    {

        private static TechTalk.SpecFlow.ITestRunner testRunner;

#line 1 "Login.feature"
#line hidden

        public LoginFeature()
        {
            this.TestInitialize();
        }

        public static void FeatureSetup()
        {
            testRunner = TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner();
            TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo featureInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "Login", "Check if Login functionality is working\r\nas expected and see if correct username " +
                    "is poping up", ProgrammingLanguage.CSharp, ((string[])(null)));
            testRunner.OnFeatureStart(featureInfo);
        }

        public static void FeatureTearDown()
        {
            testRunner.OnFeatureEnd();
            testRunner = null;
        }

        public virtual void TestInitialize()
        {
        }

        public virtual void ScenarioTearDown()
        {
            testRunner.OnScenarioEnd();
        }

        public virtual void ScenarioSetup(TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
        {
            testRunner.OnScenarioStart(scenarioInfo);
        }

        public virtual void ScenarioCleanup()
        {
            testRunner.CollectScenarioErrors();
        }

        public virtual void SetFixture(LoginFeature.FixtureData fixtureData)
        {
        }

        void System.IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            this.ScenarioTearDown();
        }
```

Any ideas what i can be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After changing the unitTestProvider in the config, you have to regenerate all code behind files. They could contain still code that is referencing NUnit classes. Did you do that already?

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal behavior since if you install  `Specflow` nuget package it will installed based on  nunit 
so you have to  `install  nuget xunit for specflow`

```
Install-Package SpecFlow.xUnit -Version 2.1.0
```

**Update** 
if you have done this try to add nunit package

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this before but found that my problem was a mismatch between the feature text vs. the signature in the step, e.g.

Feature text:
`Given I have a widget id "123"`

Step signature:
`Given I have a widgetid "123"`

Ensuring all feature texts and step signatures matched solved the problem for me.

I don't know why the error was about a missing nunit dependency though, since I was using xunit.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had this happen to me.  It was a self-inflicted wound, as it turned out.

The problem was that, in a post-build event, I was copying the config file from the application under test to be the config file of the test project.  In the post-build event for the app, I had this line, which copies the config to the Tests folder.

copy  "$(ProjectDir)"\App.config "$(SolutionDir)"\ReleaseImagesWreckersTests\App.Config

The config file being copied from the application under test did not have the lines in them that tell SpecFlow to use xUnit.   The copy was occurring before the SpecFlow tests were being built.
Eventually, I figured it out and added these lines to my app.config for the application (assembly) under test:

```
    <specFlow>
      <unitTestProvider name="xUnit" />
   </specFlow></configuration>
```

After doing that, everything worked fine.  The app under test was building successfully and then copying its config, with no specFlow section, over the top of the test assembly's config, which had the proper specFlow section before getting copied over.